# The set $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ is denumerable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be given by $f(m,n)=2^{m-1}(2n-1)$.

1-1: Suppose $f(m,n)=f(a,b)\implies 2^{m-1}(2n-1)=2^{a-1}(2b-1)$.
Since $2n-1$ and $2b-1$ are always odd, they will never by powers of 2. Thus,
$2^{m-1}(2n-1)=2^{a-1}(2b-1)\implies 2^{m-1}=2^{a-1}\implies m-1=a-1\implies m=a$.

Thus, we have $2^{m-1}(2n-1)=2^{m-1}(2b-1)\implies 2n-1=2b-1\implies n=b$.
Thus, $(m,n)=(a,b)$.

Onto: Let $y=2^{m-1}(2n-1)\in\mathbb{N}\implies 2^{m-1}\in\mathbb{N}$(even) and $2n-1\in\mathbb{N}$(odd)
$\implies m\in\mathbb{N}(m\geq1)$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}(n\geq1)$
$\implies (m,n)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$.
Thus for every $y\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists and $(m,n)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ such that
$f(m,n)=y$.

Hence, $f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ is 1-1 and onto, which implies that
$\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\approx\mathbb{N}\implies \mathbb{N}$ is denumerable.

I just wanted to know if this proof was sufficient.

Comment: Is $0 \in \Bbb{N}$ in your context?

Comment: No, the book we are using set $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,...\}$

Comment: OK. Then your proof looks right. This is one of those constructions that is much easier to understand if you do take $0$ to be a natural number: the representation of $(m, n)$ is then the number whose binary representation is the concatenation of $m$ in binary, $0$ and then $n$ in unary.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that representation around, but the book we are using uses this function to showcase $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\approx\mathbb{N}$. However, the book does not give justification for it being 1-1 and onto, so I wanted other people's input on the matter. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Every natural number $n$ has a **unique** representation as product of a power of $2$ (which can be $1= 2^0$ too) and an odd number. Algorithmically, just keep dividing $n$ by $2$ until we have an odd number left. By the unique factorisation (a weak form) the exponent of $2$ is uniquely determined and hence so is the odd remainder.

The power of two can be uniquely written as $2^{m-1}$ for $m \in \Bbb N$, and the odd number as $2n-1$ with $n \in \Bbb N$ as well. This is all the proof of $f$ being a bijection.